# Is there a way we can detect if a font is Serif or SansSerif in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list of all system fonts, in which I need to check if font is Serif / SansSerif.
I tried checking it via

```
bool isSerif = font.styleHint() & QFont::Serif 
bool isSansSerif = font.styleHint() & QFont::SansSerif
```

but this doesn't seem to be working.
I am using Qt 5.15

Comment: Qt has [QFontDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdialog.html) class

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but is QFont::family() what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check the signature: `QFont::StyleHint QFont::styleHint() const`

`styleHint` is a function and has to be called:

```cpp
bool isSerif = font.styleHint() & QFont::Serif;
bool isSansSerif = font.styleHint() & QFont::SansSerif;
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#styleHint

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong formatting here , in the code I am using font.styleHint() only and that doesn't seem to be working right

Comment: @Pickaboo check out more fonts, not every font has all these information filed in :-/